# Rails + Cucumber/Capybara: How to set/retrieve cookies in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, capybara

I'm implementing a lazy login feature. My cucumber feature should describe it:

```
    Feature: User log in

        Scenario: Lazy login
            Given I didn't log out the last time I was on the site
            When I go to the homepage
            Then I should automatically be logged in
```

And these are my step definitions:

```
Given(/^I didn't log out the last time I was on the site$/) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in('user[email]', with: user.email)
  fill_in('user[password]', with: 'test123')
  click_button('Sign in')

  Capybara.reset_sessions!
end

When(/^I go to the homepage$/) do
  visit root_path
end

Then(/^I should automatically be logged in$/) do #<-- Fails here
  page.should have_content("Logout")
end
```

This is what happens when a user logs in: the `cookies.signed[:auth_token]` gets set. This will be used by a before filter in my ApplicationController so that users who open a fresh browser will be logged in automatically:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
  super
  if user_signed_in?
    puts 'yesssssss'
    session[:user_id] = current_user.id  
    current_user.remember_me! if current_user.remember_token.blank?
    cookies.signed[:auth_token] = {
      :value => current_user.remember_token,
      :domain => "mysite.com",
      :secure => !(Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?)
      }
    puts "current_user.remember_token = #{current_user.remember_token}"
    puts 'cookies:'
    puts cookies.signed[:auth_token]
  end
end
```

end

This is the before filter in my ApplicationController:

```
def sign_in_through_cookie
  logger.info "logging in by cookie"
  puts "logging in by cookie"
  puts cookies.signed[:auth_token] #<-- PROBLEM: this returns nil.
  return true if !current_user.nil?
  if !cookies[:auth_token].nil? && cookies[:auth_token] != ''
    user = User.find_by_remember_token(cookies.signed[:auth_token])
    return false if user.blank?
    sign_in(user)
    puts 'success'
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

So the issue is that in the last step of my cucumber feature, `cookies.signed[:auth_token]` returns nil. I'm guessing this is just a capybara thing. So do I actually have to set a cookie in the test as opposed to using the one in my controller?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So eventually I figured it out after trying a lot of different things.

```
Given(/^I didn't log out the last time I was on the site$/) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in('user[email]', with: user.email)
  fill_in('user[password]', with: 'test123')
  click_button('Sign in')

  Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies.[]('auth_token').should_not be_nil
  auth_token_value = Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies.[]('auth_token')
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  page.driver.browser.set_cookie("auth_token=#{auth_token_value}")
end

When(/^I go to the homepage$/) do
  visit root_path
end

Then(/^I should automatically be logged in$/) do
  page.should have_content("Logout")
end
```

UPDATE:

Here's what I use in case I'm using Selenium for some of the tests:

```
if Capybara.current_session.driver.class == Capybara::Selenium::Driver
  auth_token = page.driver.browser.manage.cookie_named('auth_token')[:value]
  page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
  page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(:name => "auth_token", :value => auth_token)
else
  puts "cookies = #{Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies}"
  Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies.[]('auth_token').should_not be_nil
  auth_token_value = Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies.[]('auth_token')
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  page.driver.browser.set_cookie("auth_token=#{auth_token_value}")
end
```

Comment: undefined method `set_cookie' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver

Comment: Instead of `Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies.[]('auth_token')`, why not use Ruby's standard sugar for hashes - ie `Capybara.current_session.driver.request.cookies['auth_token']`

Comment: For the Poltergeist driver, the method (as documented on [the Poltergeist GitHub page](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist)) is `page.driver.set_cookie()`, and its 3 arguments are the cookie's name, its value, and an options hash for setting, among other things, the cookie's expiry value.

Comment: If you get the error

`undefined method set_cookie for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:
`

then you can set cookies like so:

`page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie(name: "cookie_name", value: "cookie_value")`

Answer (score 11):

Use https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies which wraps the driver methods. It has methods for getting cookies, deleting cookies, and a method for creating cookies called `create_cookie`.

Comment: @JonKern glad to hear it! I see that `create_cookie` has been documented in the README, so I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I needed just to test the cookie values

Inspiration taken from https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2012/01/05/capybara-cucumber-and-how-the-cookie-crumbles

and ported to Rails 5.x

Create `features/support/cookies.rb`

With content

```
module Capybara
  class Session
    def cookies
      @cookies ||= ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rails.application.env_config.deep_dup).cookie_jar
    end
  end
end

Before do
  allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:cookie_jar).and_return(page.cookies)
  allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:cookies).and_return(page.cookies)
end
```

Then the step for testing

```
Then('is set cookie {string} with value {string}') do |cookie, value|
  expect(page.cookies.signed[cookie]).to eq value
end
```

Comment: The solution is not on the page from the link you gave anymore